# Copy AD users from one Windows server 2012 R2 to another

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

We are setting up our prod machines in azure cloud. So we need to copy our Active Directory users from existing prod machine which is on premise. When I searched for options, I got articles related to restoring Server state which will have AD back up as well. But I want to restore only AD users. Can you please tell me if there is any way to do it?

Comment: In general, are you asking how to migrate from an On-Prem directory to an Azure Active Directory? Is your specific requirement to only sync your users to the cloud? Have you taken a look at [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect)?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to export the users from existing on-premises domain controller. You can leverage the Powershell Script below to export AD users to CSV.

[Powershell Script to export Active Directory users to CSV](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-script-to-5edcdaea#content)

Then, you can import the CSV by using the command below from Active Directory Powershell module. For more details, you can refer to the following article.

```
Import-CSV C:\Users.csv | New-ADUser
```

[Import Bulk Users to Active Directory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/bettertogether/2011/01/09/import-bulk-users-to-active-directory/)

Also, there is a tool which can also be used to import the CSV into Active Directory. You can get it from the link below.

[Active Directory User Creation tool 1.2](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/New-User-Creation-tool-14fa73cd#content)